# How to get the insertion point of an int input in an ArrayList without using Collections.binarySearch

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, collections, binary-search

Having a method and arr being already sorted...

```
public int search(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int numberToBeSearched) {
    //Code here
    return //insertion point
}
```

Let arr be{1, 4, 7} and numberToBeSearched 2.
return would be 1 because it would be between 1 and 4 in order to maintain the order.

How would you guys get the insertion point of numberToBeSearched inside arr without using Collections.binarySearch?

The insertion point is the index position where
the number would need to be inserted in the array-list so as to maintain the sort order.

Comment: Why is it a duplicate? I am not inserting nothing here??? Just getting the insertion point index

Comment: you can return the index instead of inserting it .

Answer (score 0):

```
        public int search(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int numberToBeSearched) {
            int i=0;
            for (i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                // if the element you are looking at is smaller than numberToBeSearched, 
                // go to the next element
                if (arr.get(i) < numberToBeSearched) continue;
                // if the element equals numberToBeSearched, return, because we don't duplicates
                if (arr.get(i) == numberToBeSearched) return -1;
                // otherwise, we have found the location of numberToBeSearched
                return i;
            }
            // we looked through all of the elements, and they were all
            // smaller than numberToBeSearched, so the index is  end of the list
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: if (arr.get(i) == numberToBeSearched) return ;
its not possible as you need to return an int

Comment: return -1 ; then it means number is already there